# how to optimise MySql function to work for concurrent users

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. Please can you advice on how can i modify below function to ensure it does not throw locking errors when called by multiple users at the same time.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_val`(`P_TABLE` VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN    
  DECLARE pk_value INT DEFAULT 0;  
  DECLARE pk_found INT DEFAULT 0;  

  SELECT 1 INTO pk_found FROM pk_keys WHERE TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE;  

  IF pk_found = 1  
  THEN    
    UPDATE pk_keys SET TABLE_VALUE = (TABLE_VALUE + 1 ) WHERE TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE;  
  ELSE  
    INSERT INTO pk_keys VALUES ( P_TABLE, 1 );  
  END IF;  

  SELECT TABLE_VALUE INTO pk_value FROM pk_keys WHERE TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE;  

  RETURN pk_value;  

END
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_val`(`P_TABLE` VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN    
  DECLARE pk_value INT DEFAULT 0;  

  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pk_keys WHERE TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE) 
  THEN
    SELECT TABLE_VALUE + 1 INTO pk_value FROM pk_keys WHERE TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE pk_keys SET TABLE_VALUE = pk_value WHERE TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE;  
  ELSE  
    SET pk_value = 1;
    INSERT INTO pk_keys VALUES ( P_TABLE, pk_value );  
  END IF;  

  RETURN pk_value;  

END
```

Have a look at [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE Locking Reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

> Let us look at another example: We have an integer counter field in a
>   table child_codes that we use to assign a unique identifier to each
>   child added to table child. It is not a good idea to use either
>   consistent read or a shared mode read to read the present value of the
>   counter because two users of the database may then see the same value
>   for the counter, and a duplicate-key error occurs if two users attempt
>   to add children with the same identifier to the table.
>
> Here, LOCK IN SHARE MODE is not a good solution because if two users
>   read the counter at the same time, at least one of them ends up in
>   deadlock when it attempts to update the counter.
>
> To implement reading and incrementing the counter, first perform a
>   locking read of the counter using FOR UPDATE, and then increment the
>   counter. For example:

```
SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE; 
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
```

> A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting
>   exclusive locks on each row it reads. Thus, it sets the same locks a
>   searched SQL UPDATE would set on the rows.

Also I replaced your if condition. `EXISTS` stops as soon as a row is found.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code? will there be any impact on the performance or retrieval time?

Comment: I doubt that it's measurable. Also consider, that security comes first, not performance. The worst thing you can have is inconsistent data.